# Why do I have Lines on My hair and How do I remove it

Tags: particles, hair

I have this baby head on which I made hair I used the Particle Edit Comb Brush. Why do I see these horizontal lines and how to remove them

Thankyou
[image]

Comment: what horitzontal lines do you mean? and please provide your blend file

Comment: The mentioned lines are the six horizontal lines created by vertical "gaps". It's on the left side of the head at the level of the ears, where the strands are disconnected (or end?). I'm not sure if it's an optical illusion. The hair seems to be very close to the head. Maybe puff it a little?